# How to programatically scroll a TextMergeViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, scrollviewer

My SWT window (Eclipse plugin) has a TextMergeViewer in it, in order to compare two files. However, I can't find a way to programmatically make it scroll up or scroll down.

If you ever used the Java compare tool in Eclipse, there is a few buttons allowing you to jump to the next/previous difference. This is what I would like to do for my viewer. How could I make it by myself ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't see any externally available methods for this. The buttons use private methods to do the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with greg-449 that functionality is hidden. if you are keen on getting it work I think you can invoke commands programmatically. This is basically what "tool bar" buttons do when clicked.

**Use commandIds:** org.eclipse.compare.selectNextChange, org.eclipse.compare.selectPreviousChange

```
IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) serviceLocator.getService(IHandlerService.class);

handlerService.executeCommand(commandId, null);
```